# Is there a way to know if finally is executed after a try or a catch?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I think the title explain whole my question.

I'd like to know, where I execute my code on `finally` statement, if it come from a `try` or a `catch`.

Is it possible?

Comment: As the last statement in your try (or in the catch) just set a boolean value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just put the code either in the try or the catch? What's your concrete case?

Comment: @devouredelysium: One situation I've used this approach in: in the finally block, I want to roll back a transaction if anything went wrong, but not if the operation was actually successful. (The last real action of the try block would be the commit.) This can *sometimes* be mitigated by putting the "don't reverse things" logic into the transaction object itself, but that's not always an option.

Comment: But why wouldn't you put that logic in the catch?

Comment: @devouredelysium: Because that requires you to *have* a `catch` block for that `Exception`. What if it's not an exception you'd anticipated? Do you have a `catch (Exception e)` block for all try blocks, just in case there's an exception you weren't aware of? You still definitely want to clean up in that situation, but then just rethrow... which is more cleanly done in the finally block, IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the simplest approach is:

```
bool success = false;
try
{
    ...
    // This should be the last statement in the try block
    success = true;
}
catch(...)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    if (success)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This isn't a specific language feature - it's just using the fact that other than *really* remarkable situations (asynchronous exceptions, basically), you're not going to get an exception occurring after the assignment to `success`.

Note that `success` being `false` doesn't mean that any of your `catch` blocks have executed - it could be that an exception was thrown which you're not catching (or that you returned before the end of the `try` block). Basically it *only* indicates "reached end of `try` block" - which is normally all that's needed.

Comment: it says the variable it is not assigned :O

Comment: @markzzz: Are you sure you included the `= false` assignment before the `try` block? If you take the exact code I've given, it should be fine.

Comment: how can I paste it to you?

Comment: @markzzz: Edit your question, or use pastebin.com. But as I say, if you're talking about the `success` variable then it clearly *is* assigned in my code - and if you're talking about another variable then you're asking me to be psychic, which is tricky...

Comment: The only difference is I have `if (txtMonitor.InvokeRequired && success)`

Comment: @markzzz: Well that doesn't even use the `success` variable, and we've no idea where those two variables are declared. Put yourself in my position, who can't see any of your code: how much chance do you think I've got of diagnosing what's wrong on the basis of just what you've told me?

Comment: @markzzz: as Jon suggested, you better edit your question and be more explicit (show your code).

Comment: Well, changing to  `if(success && txtMonitor.InvokeRequired)` :O That's really strange :)

Comment: @markzzz: Poor show on changing your comment after I'd replied to it, making my comment look crazy (your variable was `folderCopied` rather than `success` when I added the comment). And without seeing the code which was apparently broken in context, it's very hard to work out what was going on.

Comment: I changed it in some seconds :) But ok now I understand the trouble, and I fix it ;) Just strange that `if(success && txtMonitor.InvokeRequired)` works and `if (txtMonitor.InvokeRequired && success)` won't, isnt it?